# Align QLabel using styleSheet

Tags: python, qt, stylesheet

Using python and QT. I would like ask you if there is a way to have QLabel aligned as central/middle

Usually I use:

```
self.label.move(0,100)
```

but I wonder is there any easier way

Comment: I recommend you  to use layouts, it is easy and quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to set something in the middle of the screen, then you can set a layout and put that QLabelinside. Once you have it, you will be able to set it where you want.

If you want to do it with a styleSheet then you can use something like

```
 .center {
      margin: auto;
      width: 60%;
      padding: 10px;
     }
```